# Typescript ignores 'typeof' operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found some weird behavior of typescript when using `typeof`

So I tried this code in TS playground:

```
type TFilters = {[key: string]: string | number | undefined}
type TParams = [string, string?]

const func = (value: string) => {}
const params: TParams = ['date', 'other']
const filters: TFilters = {date: 'test'}

if(typeof filters[params[0]] === "string") {
  func(filters[params[0]])
}
```

I am checking that type of `filters[params[0]]` is `string`, but at `func(filters[params[0])` ts throws error:
`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

As I understand typescript, it should respect `typeof` check, isn't it?

Check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgSwDbAgJwM5QLxQN4DaA1hCAFxQbBoIB2A5gLoVU0NQA%20UtArgLYAjdJyg9aAEwgAzOhHEBfAFChIsAAoBDNBr5ZcBVnXoAaStSMB%20RosUBjAPa0qUKWNs4oACgBuGpDwgWcwYAShwAPnwlBydgKDAtHQwKGE1tXQ8CAHJxDVQs0yz7YAALdCzrGOcZFHRk2ERazA88XNQKLNQqLKVFBClPFQh7KRdkVEwCBPSMAgAGRkYcbFwAIkMGVbC8RSgXN08aidnppPnFkMV5IA)

Comment: You need to put the `filters[params[0]]` into a variable first.

Comment: Typeof checks if variable is string, your understanding is correct. The problem is when you call func function